# Debug trait not implemented for some enum variants

Tags: rust

I have this enum:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum TokenType {
    Illegal,
    Integer(String),
    Ident(String),
}

fn main() {
    let vals = vec![(TokenType::Ident, "identifier")];
    println!("Expected one of {:?}", vals);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=54d4d86395a04723ad960814bc3067a9)

When I try to use a `TokenType` value, it appears to be ignoring the `Debug` derivation, and I get the following compiler error:

```
error[E0277]: `fn(std::string::String) -> TokenType {TokenType::Ident}` doesn't implement `std::fmt::Debug`
  --> src/main.rs:10:38
   |
10 |     println!("Expected one of {:?}", vals);
   |                                      ^^^^ `fn(std::string::String) -> TokenType {TokenType::Ident}` cannot be formatted using `{:?}` because it doesn't implement `std::fmt::Debug`
   |
   = help: the trait `std::fmt::Debug` is not implemented for `fn(std::string::String) -> TokenType {TokenType::Ident}`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::fmt::Debug` for `(fn(std::string::String) -> TokenType {TokenType::Ident}, &str)`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::fmt::Debug` for `std::vec::Vec<(fn(std::string::String) -> TokenType {TokenType::Ident}, &str)>`
   = note: required by `std::fmt::Debug::fmt`
```

It would appear to me that the issue is because I have a few variants of that enum that contain a `String` (ex. `Ident(String)`) it's not properly deriving the `Debug` trait, but I don't know how to resolve it.

Is there some way to force Rust to derive the trait for that enum or is there a way that I can resolve this error by manually implementing `fmt::Debug` for those variants?

Comment: What does this `vals` vector mean? What are you trying to output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TokenType::Ident` is **not** an enum variant; it is an enum variant *constructor*. The error message points out that it is a function:

```
fn(std::string::String) -> TokenType {TokenType::Ident}
```

Functions do not implement `Debug`. There is no solution for what you want.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that those were considered functions, but I guess that would make sense. So there's no way to implement `Debug` on an enum like that, even manually?

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness `Debug` is implemented for a value of the enum; you don't *have* a value of the enum.

Comment: Maybe it helps: TokenType::Ident(String::from("hi")) - is the value